# Manifest not processed when loading module

Tags: powershell, module, manifest, powershell-3.0

I've created a PowerShell module and a manifest but it seems like the manifest is not processed when loading the module.

I've created a very simple example with the same behaviour:

`TestModule.psm1`

```
function Foo
{
    return "Bar"
}
```

I then create a manifest like this:

```
$version = New-Object System.Version(0, 0, 1, 0)

New-ModuleManifest -Author "Remko Weijnen" -Description "TestModule" -ModuleVersion $version  -PowerShellVersion 3.0 `
    -Path ".\TestModule.psd1" -RootModule ".\TestModule.psm1"
```

I've created a folder `TestModule` and placed `TestModule.psm1` and `TestModule.psd1` inside it.

When importing the manifest the version is recognised correctly:

```
Import-Module .\TestModule.psd1
Get-Module TestModule | select name, version

Name       Version
----       -------
TestModule 0.0.1.0
```

However when I load the module the version is not recognised:

```
Import-Module .\TestModule.psm1
Get-Module TestModule | select name, version

Name       Version
----       -------
TestModule 0.0
```

Am I missing something? Or is it not supposed to work like this?

Comment: If you place your folder in the `<user>\documents\windowspowershell\modules` folder, and just do `import-module testmodule`, does the version show up correctly?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician yes that works

Comment: Then this is pretty much how you should expect it to work. When you explicitly import the .psm1 file you bypass the manifest. There's nothing in the .psm1 file that says to load the manifest. If you follow "normal" module behavior as described in my first comment then the manifest is loaded as expected. Does this answer your question?

Comment: If you change your comment to an answer I can accept it. This confirmed what I was thinking (was hoping to be wrong though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty much how you should expect it to work. When you explicitly import the .psm1 file you bypass the manifest. There's nothing in the .psm1 file that says to load the manifest. If you follow "normal" module behavior (by "installing" the module to a path listed in the modulepath environmental variable) then the manifest is loaded as expected.

Comment: Do note that you can also import the `.psd1` file, instead of the `.psm1`. In that case, it will obviously pick up both files --- because the `.psd1` file does (implicitly or explicitly) specify which module to import.